# Airflow no module named for directory in airflow_home directory

Tags: python, airflow

I'm working with virtualenv. I i'm trying to use packages inside DAG folders. Current state of `airflow_home` directory is:

```
airflow_home/airflow.cfg
airflow_home/airflow.db
airflow_home/dags/__init__.py 
airflow_home/dags/hello_world.py
airflow_home/dags/support/inner.py
airflow_home/dags/support/__init__.py
```

hello_world.py has code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from dags.support import inner


def print_hello():
    return 'Hello world'

dag = DAG('hello_world', description='simple tutorial DAG',
          schedule_interval='0 12 * * *', start_date=datetime(2017, 8, 20), catchup=False)

dummy_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_task', retries=3, dag=dag)

hello_operator = PythonOperator(task_id='hello_task', python_callable=print_hello, dag=dag)

hello_from_inner_operator = PythonOperator(task_id='hello_from_inner', python_callable=inner.hello_from_inner, dag=dag)

dummy_operator >> hello_operator
hello_operator >> hello_from_inner_operator
```

If i could manually run this script, it runs. But then i start airflow scheduler,

```
Broken DAG: No module named 'dags'
```

error appears. What i'm doing wrong, what is the way to solve this ?

Comment: I'm new to Airflow, but I'm assuming its a path issue.  Are you able to do `from support import inner`?

Comment: Yes, from support import inner working well.

Comment: Ok, great.  and that works when the AF scheduler runs it too?

Comment: yeah. from support import inner also working perfect in airflow scheduler session.

Comment: Hi I'm having the same issue, were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 16):

use `from support import inner` instead.

the path `$AIRFLOW_HOME/dags` will be added into `sys.path` when airflow starts. So it will search modules under `dags` directory.

Comment: in the IDE, it will say something like `Unresolved reference 'inner'`. How can I set so it will not pop that kind of error?

Comment: I think add the dag_folder into the PYTHONPATH can solve this problem. `export PYTHONPATH=<path_to_dag_folder>`

Comment: @Freedom I have imported a python file to my dag file as `from work_file import Test` instead of `from dags.work_file import Test` no error on the UI, but dag is not visible on UI. Please help

Comment: @AmanRaheja You need to confirm that your DAG definition is correct. And confirm the `dags_folder` is set correctly in `airflow.cfg`.

Comment: The `dags_folder` should contain the `dags` folder path. right?. Currently, it is set to `/usr/local/airflow/dags`

Comment: @Freedom Here is my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62327923/dag-is-not-visible-on-airflow-ui

Comment: I have the same problem, and this solution didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a package installed *inside* the virtualenv, and you run an instance of airflow that's *outside* of that virtualenv, it might not know that you want it to use the virtualenv.

To see if you have this problem, run:

```
(myAwesomeVenv) $ which airflow

    /path/to/some/airflow
```

If it gives a path outside of your virtualenv, then be sure that airflow is in the virtualenv, and that you're calling the right one.

I did `pip install apache-airflow` inside of my virtualenv, and then hid the external instance like so:

```
 mv /home/matt/.local/bin/airflow /home/matt/.local/bin/airflow.bak
```

Following this, I got:

```
(myAwesomeVenv) $ which airflow

    /home/matt/src/foo/venv/bin/airflow
```

...and my imports started working.