# DAG is not visible on Airflow UI

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-scheduler

This is my dag file in `dags` folder.

```
Code that goes along with the Airflow located at:
http://airflow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html
"""
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from work_file import Test


class Main(Test):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__()

    def create_dag(self):
        default_args = {
            "owner": "airflow",
            "depends_on_past": False,
            "start_date": datetime(2015, 6, 1),
            "email": ["airflow@airflow.com"],
            "email_on_failure": False,
            "email_on_retry": False,
            "retries": 1,
            "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
            # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
            # 'pool': 'backfill',
            # 'priority_weight': 10,
            # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
        }
        dag = DAG("python_dag", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='0 * * * *')

        dummy_task = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_task', retries=3)

        python_task = PythonOperator(task_id='python_task', python_callable=self.my_func)

        dummy_task >> python_task


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Main()
    a.create_dag()
```

**This is my other file `work_file.py` which is in the same `dags` folder.**

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def my_func(self):
        return "Hello"
```

**Aim**:-The Aim is to call the `my_func` from my dag file.

**Problem**:- There seems to be no error on the UI,but my dag `python_dag` is not visible.

My server, scheduler is also running, I've tried restarting the same but nothing happened.

I have imported the file as well (`from work_file import Test`)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems with the DAG:

1. The operators are not assigned to any DAG. Add `dag=dag` to the constructors. E.g., `DummyOperator(..., dag=dag)`.
2. `create_dag()` does not return the DAG. Add `return dag`.
3. The DAG script is not executed as the top level code. That is, the modules `__name__` is never `'__main__'`. Remove `if __name__ == "__main__":`.
4. The DAG objects must be in the global namespace of the module. Assign the return value of `create_dag()` to a variable: `dag = a.create_dag()`.